# Flash AS3 - Creating BadGuys that make me lose

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I just trying to copy the same question, because i need really the answet to it

So, i have a problem here...

I want to creat every "x" tyme a bad guy in my game and when it collide with the player, i lose a life. Simple...

But whenever it creats a new bad guy, the previous ones lose their instance name or something and i dont lose a life because it doesnt not recognise the "bad guy" instance...

What i have to do? I want that all the bad guys in the field can make the player lose a life.

I'm using this code to create the new bad guy:

```
contadorTempo.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, intervaloTempo2);//evento para nascimento do mau da direta

function intervaloTempo2(evento:TimerEvent):void
{
  //código para o novo mau nascer
  mau=new Black_Player ();
  addChild (mau);
  mau.rotation = 180; //rotação do mau
  mau.x = 1024; //posição de x do mau é igual a 0
  mau.y = Math.random()*540; //posição y do mau é feita aleatóriamente entre os valores 1 e 540 de y 
  mau.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, movermau2);//quando nasce o novo mau, esta   função faz-lo mover-se da direita

}//função para nasimento do mau  da direita
```

And, for the collision with the player, im using this code:

```
stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, perdervida);

function perdervida(evento:Event):void
{

    if( jogador_bom.hitTestObject(mau) == true ){

    vida = vida - 1;
    mau.x = 10000;

    trace("AUCH");

    livetext.text = String(vida); // código para aparecer o número de vidas do jogador no ecra
}

} //função para perder uma vida
```

PS: sorry about the english, not my language, and i hope u understand my question, and i hope this insert code is good like the others question. I spent like 20 minutes just to figure this out. First time here.
eeee

Cheers :)

Comment: You shouldn't post your own duplicate questions. Especially not after two hours. Have some patience. If you want to get your question up you can do it by refining it and adding more details. To get a broader audience you could also translate your source into english. Even though it seems irrelevant, it makes it hard to read for non Spanish speakers. Or is it Portuguese?

Answer (score 0):

You need to store all the created 'bad guys' in an array. The way this looks now I think you are overwriting the one 'bad guy' instance every time you make a new one.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an array to hold your bad guys

```
var _badGuys:Array = new Array();
```

Then push all your bad guys in it.

```
function intervaloTempo2(evento:TimerEvent):void {
    mau=new Black_Player ();
    _badGuys.push(mau);
    addChild (mau);
    mau.rotation = 180;
    mau.x = 1024;
    mau.y = Math.random()*540;
    mau.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, movermau2);
}
```

Then you can create a for loop to check collision with each bad guys from the array...

```
for (var i:Number = 0; i < _badGuys.length; i++){
    if(jogador_bom.hitTestObject(_badGuys[i])){
        vida = vida - 1;
        mau.x = 10000;
        livetext.text = String(vida);
    }
}
```